# Does symmetric matrices which is invertible always has principal non singular submatrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric matrix of order $n \times n$. Let it is of rank $r$. Could you say that it always has a non singular principal  sub matrix of order $k\le n$?

Since it has rank $r$, there must exist non singular sub matrix of order $k\le n$. Otherwise, it would never have rank above that $k$. But I don't think it happens for principal sub matrix also. I am not getting any example

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &2\\ 2&0 \end{bmatrix}$. Do you see that it has no non singular principal sub matrix of order $1$ ?